# Change per-page results on WP search while retaining query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site with a standard search option. On the search results page I need to offer a select field that allows the user to show 12, 24, 36, or all results. Seems simple enough, but I'm having trouble with the URL string.

My code assigns the current query string to a variable, which I then pass into the select field and append the per_page to it. That works fine. The issue is that each time I change the select field, it appends the per_page to the end of the URL. So if I select 12 then change it to 24, my URL winds up being /?s=search-term&per_page=12&per_page=24

My question is, how do I get it to replace the per_page in the URL as opposed to appending to it?

Many thanks for any help

```
<?php $search_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>

Show<select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="?<?php echo $search_string . '&per_page=12';?>">12</option>
        <option value="?<?php echo $search_string . '&per_page=24';?>">24</option>
        <option value="?<?php echo $search_string . '&per_page=36';?>">36</option>
        <option value="?<?php echo $search_string . '&per_page=-1';?>">All</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will remove it from your query string prior to printing it on each option.

```
$search_string = preg_replace('#&?per_page=([\d]+)&?#', '', $search_string);
```

Comment: Great. Could you please accept this as the accepted answer? Thanks